# Microsoft Teams dont send authorization hash to php header

Tags: php, hash, hmac

I have some some problem...

I create an Microsoft Team WEBHOOK:

[WEBHOOK Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjqAo.png)

[WEBHOOK Secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh32N.png)

But teams dont send hmac hash authorization to my PHP Script header...

```
<?php
//The secret share with Microsoft Teams
$secret = "{MY TEAMS WEBHOOK SECRET}";

//get headers
$a = getallheaders();
$provided_hmac = substr($a['Authorization'],5);

//Get data from request
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

//json decode into array
$json = json_decode($data, true);

//hashing
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256",$data,base64_decode($secret), true);
$calculated_hmac = base64_encode($hash);

//start log var
$log = "\n========".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."========\n".$provided_hmac."\n".$calculated_hmac."\n";

try{
    //compare hashs
    if(hash_equals($provided_hmac,$calculated_hmac))
        throw new Exception("No hash matching");
    //response text
    $txt="Hi {$json["from"]["name"]} welcome to your custom bot";
    echo '{
        "type": "message",
        "text": "'.$txt.'"
         }';
    $log .= "Sended: {$txt}";
}catch (Exception $e){
    $log .= $e->getMessage();
}

//write log
$fp = fopen("log.txt","a");
fwrite($fp, $log . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Any one can help me with this ?

I try some methods but dont work.

Header dont have any part/string with authorization hash...

Thanks for help.